# How to move a div element above another using CSS

Tags: html, css

I really need help! I have a comment section on my website and have been trying for the life of me to get my date and time to come below the posted comment itself. I have figured out how to rearrange it in the html file, but unfortunately can't seem to find that file in my things (i used chrome developer to rearrange it).

I am wondering if there is a way I can place the date below the comment by using CSS? I've attached a picture below of what the comment section looks like currently.

[image: Comment Section Appearance]

Thanks so much for any advice in advance!

Comment: can you share the code please.

Comment: Without seeing code that you are working with, we won't be able to help you.

Comment: "_can I place the date below the comment by using CSS?_" Yes.

Answer (score 0):

You can easly do it with CSS if you don't want to rearrange the elements with HTML. I don't know if this is the solution you are looking for but you can give position relative to the comment container and then just position element with date as absolute on the bottom.

```
.comment {
    position:relative;
    padding-bottom:20px;
}
.comment .date {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

This makes the element with date appear on the bottom of a comment, and the extra padding-bottom on a comment container makes sure that the date has enough space to be displayed without overlapping any comment text (you might want to adjust that padding-bottom value to your own taste)